# Sistema de rank ordem maior para menor

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Como o titulo diz eu estou com dificuldade para colocar um sistema de rank do maior para o menor número.

Meu sistema fica na ordem do banco de dados

ordem no banco de dados = 10,9,6,8,2,3  <- fica na msm ordem na minha página.

```
       if(isset($_POST["uid"])) {
    $id = protege($_POST["uid"]);
    $my = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM Banco WHERE id=:id");
    $my->bindValue(":id", $id);
    if($my->execute()) {
        if($my->rowCount() > 0) {
            $fetch = $my->fetch();
            $pontos = (int)$fetch["pontos"];
            $pontos++;
            $q = $PDO->prepare("UPDATE Banco SET pontos=:pontos");
            $q->bindValue(":pontos", $pontos);
            if($q->execute()) {
                echo '{"pontos":"'.$pontos.'"}';
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
function pegarUsuarios() {
                global $PDO;
                $query = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM Banco");
                if($query->execute()) {
                    while($fetch = $query->fetch()) {
                        echo '<li>'.protege($fetch["id"]).'</li><li onclick=\'ponto('.protege($fetch["id"]).')\'>'.protege($fetch["name"]).'</li><li id="'.protege($fetch["id"]).'">'.protege($fetch["pontos"]).'</li>';
                    }
                }
            }
```

eu queria deixar nessa ordem = 10,9,8,6,3,2

Comment: Não basta adicionar `ORDER BY <coluna> DESC` na sua consulta?

Comment: E se o objetivo do primeiro código é apenas incrementar o número de pontos, basta fazer algo como `update Banco set pontos = pontos + 1 where id=:id`. Isso evitaria de ter que fazer o *select* apenas para pegar o valor atual da pontuação.

Comment: Nossa man fui meio batata agora ''/ só precisava de um ORDER BY pontos DESC.

Comment: Se colocar `ASC` a ordenação ficará crescente. Pelo enunciado você deseja decrescente, então deverá utilizar `DESC`.